# Read decimal values in SAS

Tags: sas

For this dataset:

```
data my;
    input x y;
    datalines;
    -122.413582861209 37.7828877716232
    -122.417876547159 37.7848288325307
;
proc print;
run;
```

The output and related tables are:

[image]

How can I import, save and use these values to their maximum precision?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full precision value is there, you just don't see it. SAS uses formats to control what it prints/shows, even if you don't notice it (there are default numeric and character formats).

Try using `FORMAT x y 17.12;` either in the data step to set it permanently, or in the `PROC PRINT` step to set it temporarily.

Comment: Note that `FORMAT x y 17.12` will show both `x` and `y` as 17 characters long (including the decimal and, when present, the negative sign), and 12 of those characters will be digits after the decimal point. Numbers with more characters or greater decimal precision may not display correctly.